# hovering single li in navigation

Tags: css, hover

Im trying to make a hover style like this picture

> [image: hover-effect]
>
> > want to increase the corresponding li height and style on hover.any idea?

Answer (score 0):

just define hover on anchor not hovering on list

change

```
.nav li:hover > a{}
```

to

```
.nav li a:hover{}
```

Comment: if you give me you menu code maybe i can help but that the to change hover like that in css

Answer (score 0):

The `a` tag in `li` style like below:

```
a:hover{line-height:100px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try like this

```
nav li:hover ul{ line-height:70px }
```